# Kernel Panic + Infinit Log In Loop

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, login

This is now the second time this has happened to me. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. One random day I attempt to boot my computer and it says

```
 Kernel Panic unable to mount root fs on unknown
```

Blah blah blah, and it can't boot the following kernel:

```
 4.10.0-35-generic
```

I have tried to go into a live cd and do all the mounting followed by the

```
 update-initramfs -u -k 4.10.0-35-generic
 update-grub
```

That allowed my computer to get past the initial kernel panic, but now I'm stuck in an infinite log in loop. The computer also doesn't recognize my GPU, and reverted back to the initial graphics. How do I fix this? I've run out of possible fixes that others have posted.

Comment: I have the same problem and my PC starts with Kernel 4.10.0-33 without problems. It could be related to `encryptfs`, because when I just click on the encrypted hard drive in Dolphin I get the following error `An error occurred while accessing '238,0 GiB Encrypted Drive', the system responded: An unspecified error has occurred: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem' on object at path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d0`.